# Threadline in CSS

Tags: html, css

I try for quite a while now to get a dynamic height line working in css.

It should connect the icons of different TextItems horizontally.

The items are dynamic, e.g. they even change on click.
I tried to do it with a pseudo element of `.item` so it would have the same height as the item, but for some reason it is always too long.

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/BCwwb

Goal: Make the threadline spawn from the first `.item` to the last `.item`, but not any further.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give `.item` `position: relative;` so that its absolutely-positioned `::before` will be positioned relative to it:

```css
.item {
    position: relative;
}
```

[Here's the updated fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/BCwwb/1/)

If you meant to hide it on the last one... then do that too :)

```css
.item:last-child::before {
    display: none;
}
```

[And another jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/BCwwb/2/)

Comment: Thanks ! That's it ! Darn .. this css. Only the upper class needed a relative .. though I thought if not defined elements were set to relative anyways ?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you simplify your solution and wrap all of your `.item` elements in a parent element. This looks like a list of items, so I'd normally use `ul` or `ol`, but if you're not into semantics, just use a `div` (which it looks like you're content with).

http://jsfiddle.net/BCwwb/3/